# how to label the nodes in a tree?

Tags: python

Say I've defined a "node" class:

```
class vertex:
    def __init__(self):
        self.leftchild = None
        self.rightchild = None
```

along with an insert function, and i've made a tree structure by iterating the insert function a bunch of times. Now say I want to somehow label the elements of my tree with the integers 0,...,n-1, where n is the size of my tree. I can probably figure out the right algorithm, but what stumps me is: i basically want a new attribute for every node (its integer label), so that I can just assign it once (via some expensive recursive algorithm), and then access the label from the node in constant time. Is there a way to assign new attributes outside of the constructor? or what's the right way to "label stuff" in that way?

Comment: Is there a way to assign new attributes outside of the constructor? Just assign them to the instance objects at runtime or inside instance methods using `self.yourattribute`

Comment: You somehow visit every node of your tree, and do the assignments.

Comment: Also `__init__` is not a constructor. It just setups the object (`__new__` is the constructor, but rarely needed)

Comment: @progmatico ahhh, i did not know i could do that. (im a complete beginner, obviously). thanks for your help

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: It seems like your `insert` function would be an easy place to add the id without having to traverse the the again.